# delete multiple files from terminal [git]

Tags: git, terminal

I deleted multiple files from a website that I am currently working on. All the files on my computer and I am using git in terminal. Terminal is telling me that there are several files that have been deleted (the ones that I deleted).

Right now I've been doing

```
git rm filename.jpg
```

to every single file that I am trying to remove. Is there a faster way to do this rather than having to remove each file one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove then in any way you find fit and just `git commit -a`.

Comment: Delete the files with whatever you want. When you `commit -a`, you commit all changes including removal of all files that are no longer in the working copy.

Comment: @StenSoft the problem here is to remove multiple files and not add and commit them. `git rm` stages the deletion as well, so `-a` option will be of no use. :)

Comment: `-a` stages all changes in the working copy including deletions.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

Eg: `git rm dir1` (To delete dir1/file1, dir1/file2 ...)
`git rm -r dir1` (to delete everything inside dir1 recursively, even sub-directories)

You can use *.c, * etc for expanding the filenames.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like StenSoft suggested, you can remove all your files manually and make a commit for all the deleted files. However, if you are strict about your git usage for deleting your files, you can slightly modify your git rm statement into

```
git rm file_1 file_2 file_3
```